# Error instalacion Plugin Cordova

Tags: cordova, plugin

Al instalar un plugin en cordova, deja de encontrar otros plugin que tengo instalados.

He buscado varios plugin y al instalarlos todos pasa lo mismo y siempre dejan de funcionar los mismos plugin.

Si no instalo nada, van todos los plugin , pero instale cual instale, sale ese error siempre de los mismo.

```
file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/www/screenorientation.android.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-cszbar/www/zbar.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cordova.js:1431 Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-screen-orientation.screenorientation.android does not exist.
```

Comment: Hola Ruben. No estás dando mucha información por lo que de momento tu problema *no es reproducible*. Puedes indicar qué plugins funcionan y cuales dejan de funcionar? Has mirado si existen incompatibilidades entre ellos¿? Un saludo

Comment: ya tienes ahi el codigo